# How can I avoid componentDidCatch() from firing something multiple times?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If a component in rendered 10 times, and has an error, `componentDidCatch()` will fire 10 times with that same error. Currently I make an API request on catch to log the error, but I only want that error logged *once*.

My first though was to save my own `prevError` in state, and check if the `error` passed to `componentDidCatch()` was the same. But that won't work since the `setState` request isn't immediate. Some other lifecycle events are passed the latest state but this isn't. I know `setState()` takes a callback with up-to-date state but by then the error will *always* be equal to the `prevError`. Here's what I mean:

```
componentDidCatch(error, info) {
    this.setState({ error: true });

    const isNewError = (error.toString() !== this.state.prevError.toString());
    // always true since setState is async
    if (isNewError) {
       logErrorToMyService(error, info); // should only run once
       this.setState({ prevError: error });
    }
}
```

I also don't think I can use `componentDidUpdate()` somehow because that doesn't know my error.

Am I missing something? Am I just handling this problem wrong and need to rework it (maybe move the check into the `logErrorToMyService` instead)?

---

A full React example of what I mean:

```js
const logErrorToMyService = () => console.warn('I should only be run once');

class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component {
  state = {
    error: false,
    prevError: new Error(), 
  }
  
  componentDidCatch(error, info) {
    this.setState({ error: true });
    
    // none of the below code will work correctly
    const isNewError = (error.toString() !== this.state.prevError.toString());
    // always true since setState is async
    if (isNewError) {
       logErrorToMyService(error, info); // should only run once
       this.setState({ prevError: error });
    }
  }
  
  render() {
    if (this.state.error) {
      return <div>Something went (purposefully) wrong.</div>;
    }
    return this.props.children;
  }  
}

// below is 10 purposefully buggy component instances
const BuggyComponent = () => (
    <div>{purposefully.throwing.error}</div>
)

const App = () => (
  <ErrorBoundary>
    {[...Array(10)].map((_, i) => <BuggyComponent key={i} />)}
  </ErrorBoundary>
)

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<div id='root'></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.3.1/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.3.1/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

---

***Update***: Along with switching `prevError` to a field on the class, I also changed it to an array so that repeat errors - but that might have a *different* error in between - are also skipped.

Comment: Don't use state then; implement `prevError` as class variable.

Comment: @ChrisG Thank you! That did it. Hmm, never thought about _not_ using state to store something like that. I wonder if there's other stuff I should be doing that for instead. If you want to add that as an official answer I can mark it as accepted.

Comment: Using `state` is supposed to make React re-render if necessary but *only* if necessary. So all variables that have an effect on `render()` should be part of `state`. Everything else can be implemented as class variable or even outside the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code you posted, `componentDidCatch()` will fire a dozen or so times in quick succession long before the `setstate` callback runs for the first time. However `prevError` doesn't have to be part of `state`, given that is has no bearing on the appearance of the component.

Just implement it as class variable instead so it is set synchronously.